Strange bash errors for root console
Frequently, when switching my user by root with su -, I get strange bash error messages in the rxvt console, or even in a TTY. They happen even after a complety system upgrade from scratch, so it is probably a thing in root HOME.
For example, these:
sh: error importing function definition for `_file'
sh: _file: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: _file: line 3: ` --help | --version | --separator | -!(-*)[vF])'

When I logout, I then get several errors like:
/bin/bash: _sudo: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: _sudo: line 19: ` --user | --other-user | -!(-*)[uU])'
/bin/bash: error importing function definition for `_sudo'

Even if I do sh in the console I get
/bin/bash: _file: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/bash: _file: line 3: ` --help | --version | --separator | -!(-*)[vF])'
/bin/bash: error importing function definition for `_file'

I then logout and login again, and the normal behavior is restored. Until it begins behaving strangely...
I thought it was a problem with '~/.bashrc' or the like, but those files are shared with my normal user that never ever shows errors in console.
There is obviously a bash script with errors, but I don't know even where to begin looking. What is _sudo?? The commands grep _sudo $(find . -type f) and find . -name _sudo show nothing...
EDIT
This is the content of my file /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo:
# bash completion for sudo(8)                              -*- shell-script -*-

_sudo()
{
    local cur prev words cword split
    _init_completion -s || return

    local i mode=normal
    [[ $1 == *sudoedit ]] && mode=edit

    [[ $mode == normal ]] &&
        for ((i = 1; i <= cword; i++)); do
            if [[ ${words[i]} != -* ]]; then
                local PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin
                local root_command=${words[i]}
                _command_offset $i
                return
            fi
            if [[ ${words[i]} == -@(!(-*)e*|-edit) ]]; then
                mode=edit
                break
            fi
            [[ ${words[i]} == \
            -@(user|other-user|group|close-from|prompt|!(-*)[uUgCp]) ]] &&
                ((i++))
        done

    case "$prev" in
        --user | --other-user | -!(-*)[uU])
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -u -- "$cur"))
            return
            ;;
        --group | -!(-*)g)
            COMPREPLY=($(compgen -g -- "$cur"))
            return
            ;;
        --close-from | --prompt | -!(-*)[Cp])
            return
            ;;
    esac

    $split && return

    if [[ $cur == -* ]]; then
        local opts=$(_parse_help "$1")
        COMPREPLY=($(compgen -W '${opts:-$(_parse_usage "$1")}' -- "$cur"))
        [[ ${COMPREPLY-} == *= ]] && compopt -o nospace
        return
    fi
    if [[ $mode == edit ]]; then
        _filedir
    fi
} &&
    complete -F _sudo sudo sudoedit

# ex: filetype=sh


What flavor or distribution of Linux? Those look like they are related to bash completions (for example /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo)

Fedora, regardless of the version. Indeed, there is a _sudo in that file! What is this file for?

... in fact they are exactly the kinds of errors you'd get from sourcing /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo with the exglob shell option unset

Yet, I have this in the .bashrc: shopt -s extglob cdspell no_empty_cmd_completion histappend checkwinsize

... the errors beginning sh: would be consistent with sourcing one of the bash completions files in a POSIX shell (for example, root's login shell is /bin/sh, and that is symlinked to dash)

Very strange, because echo $SHELL, awk -F: -v user="root" '$1 == user {print $NF}' /etc/passwd and getent passwd root | awk -F: '{print $NF}' all report /bin/bash. So maybe the root shell somehow changes...? My /bin/sh points to bash.

The version of bash-completions used in the version of Fedora OP is using does not match the upstream. The upstream version of completions/sudo does not have the _sudo function, but _comp_cmd_sudo. In any case, sourcing the file in eg. mksh produces the error unexpected '((' on line 13, since for (( ... )) is a bashism.

If it is a Fedora thing, then this is not going to be fixed anytime soon. It is a waste of time to submit bugs to Fedora, they are simply ignored. About the second part, my root uses bash.

I just noticed that the version of the file completions/sudo from the tag v2.11.0, which is used to create the bash-completion package in OpenBSD, has the function named _sudo, and is different from the main branch, which has the function named _comp_cmd_sudo.

@Vilinkameni "since for (( ... )) is a bashism". Note that that construct is from ksh93, not bash and is also supported by zsh.

@StéphaneChazelas Ok, my bad. I meant "non-POSIX".

To answer the question formally, and as mentioned by @steeldriver in the comments, _sudo is the name of the function from the file completions/sudo from the bash-completion project.
The given error messages appear when a dot or source utility is attempted with that file as argument, from within Bash with the option extglob unset, which is the default¹. This happens because the line 19 contains the extended pattern matching operators @() and !():
if [[ ${words[i]} == -@(!(-*)e*|-edit) ]]; then

However, as @Stéphane Chazelas noted (see footnote), extended pattern matching operators should work within [[ ... ]] on the right-hand side of == since Bash 4.1, so this might not be the actual source of the issue. According to the given error message, the problematic line seems to be line 29:
--user | --other-user | -!(-*)[uU])

Similarly, !() is used in the file completions/file:
--help | --version | --separator | -!(-*)[vF])

Here is the example usage of dot utility with the file path from OpenBSD (the exact location might vary on other systems):
. /usr/local/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo

A command like the one above is likely contained within one of the initialization files, or the scripts called from them.
The (deprecated) option - instructs su(1) to execute the shell (according to the comments, Bash) of the user in question (without arguments, root) as an (interactive) login shell.
When executed as an interactive login shell, Bash sources /etc/profile, and after that file, the first existing file from the following list, in order:

~/.bash_profile,
~/.bash_login, or
~/.profile.

For the root user, substitute ~ with /root:

/root/.bash_profile,
/root/.bash_login, or
/root/.profile.

Along with /etc/profile, those are the files to check for the sourcing of the file completions/sudo. A line
shopt -s extglob

should be added to that file, before the sourcing of completions/sudo.
Note: This might affect security, since it enables root's shell to use extended globbing, which is otherwise turned off.

¹ Note by @Stéphane Chazelas: Since bash 4.1 extglob operators (a subset of ksh's extended glob operators) are available in [[...]] pattern matching operators regardless of whether the option is enabled globally or not.

Since bash 4.1 extglob operators (a subset of ksh's extended glob operators) are available in [[...]] pattern matching operators regardless of whether the option is enabled globally or not.

Note that -@(!(-*)e*|-edit) also matches on -uVilinkameni for instance.

Thanks, added the note.

The OP then probably doesn't use Bash ≥ 4.1, since he is having this issue.

Another option is that the OP is simply using another version of completions/sudo,  since the exact error message he reported contains --user | --other-user | -!(-*)[uU]), which is within case and not [[ ... ]].

@Vilinkameni No, I am using bash 5.2, and /etc/profile and /etc/profiles.d/* do not contain any reference to sudo, nor the scripts they source. Hence, I still do not understand where the origin of this intermittent problem is. The /root/.bash_profile sources  /root/.bashrc which itself contains shopt -s extglob. I added an EDIT with the contents of my /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo.

The file /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/sudo is not relevant, since its contents comes from upstream. What is relevant is which file ends up sourcing that file. The command I gave is just an example. The actual command might use globs or other means to source the completions, eg. for c in /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/*; do . $c; done or use find to obtain the list of files and source them, etc. As I stated, this can even be done by executing a function from an external script from an initialization file.

The only reason I discussed the version of the file completions/sudo are the line numbers reported in the error messages, which don't match the line numbers from the same file from v2.11.0. But again, that is irrelevant to the issue from the question.

As stated in my answer, the command shopt -s extglob should be added before the sourcing of files containing completion functions, wherever that might be. So again, what might be helpful is the actual contents of the initialization files in question. Also a reminder, sourcing could be done either with a . or the source utility, and could be "hidden" in a separate function.

This might be the place where files are sourced, for example (function __load_completion called internally from the script bash_completion). That script  sets shopt -s extglob, by the way.

Quoting the README.md: "These commands install the completions and helpers, as well as a profile.d script that loads bash_completion where appropriate. If your system does not use the profile.d directory (usually below /etc) mechanism (i.e., does not automatically source shell scripts in it), you can source the $sysconfdir/profile.d/bash_completion.sh script in /etc/bashrc or ~/.bashrc."

Sorry, my bad. Yes, this is the chain of sources in my Fedora: /etc/profile sources /etc/profile.d/, /etc/profile.d/bash_completion.sh sources /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion which in turn sources /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/. So I guess I could create a /etc/profile.d/00_fixextglob.sh with shopt -s extglob, hoping that no one is sourcing it before.

Actually, as you observed, extglob is set in bash-completion/bash_completion before sourcing the sudo file, so my solution above is no solution at all. Anyway, I really don't understand is why it is intermittent, and why does not happen right away but after some time in sudo.

This seems normal, so the only possibility that I can think of right now is that the files from /usr/share/bash-completion/completions are sourced elsewhere. Without the contents of initialization files, I can only guess. Bash command line completion is something that should work out of the box, without the need for explicit setup. In any case, I'd try putting shopt -s extglob 2>/dev/null || true at the very top of /etc/profile. (If this form is not used, non-Bash/non-POSIX shells  would emit a warning or, depending on errexit, exit.)

Yes, I have no idea why this is not working out of the box. Ok, I will use the form you suggested. I will make the change you suggested when mine fails. And if that still fails, I will put it in the top of sudo and file scrips, or even inside the functions _sudo and _file. That should do it. :) Thanks for your time!!
